# How set url in Javascript (js.erb) with Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this

**route**:

```
put :sort, :path => 'activities/sort', :controller => 'activities'
```

**JS**:

```
url: '/activities/sort',
```

**I want to convert to this (without use controller name or :as attribute)**:

```
url: <%= :action => 'sort' %>,
```

or the same href of something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Order by name",
         :sort,
         :method => :put %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write in routes this url. Like:

**config/routes.rb**

```
match 'activities/sort_by_attr' => 'activities#sort', :as => :sort_by_attr
```

then write

```
url: <%= sort_by_attr_path %>,
```

Comment: There is no other way? Like this:  `<%= link_to "Sort",
             :sort,
             :method => :put %>
             ` or something

Answer (score 1):

You would've defined routes like this `resources :activities` in `routes.rb` which will give you seven RESTful routes for free. However, You are not limited to the seven routes that RESTful routing creates by default. If you like, you may add additional routes that apply to the collection or individual members of the collection.

```
resources :activities do
  collection do
    get 'sort_by_attr'
  end
end
```

Or

```
resources :activities do
  get 'sort_by_attr', :on => :collection
end
```

You can specify a name for any route using the **:as** option as in:

```
resources :activities do
  get 'sort_by_attr', :on => :collection, :as => :sort
end
```

which will give you `sort_activities_path` and `sort_activities_url`. Read more about [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

**EDIT:**

If you just pass in `:action` parameter to link_to it would try to find that route in the current controller and render that action. Although not recommended, you can try defining a generic route to match any url like this:

```
match ':controller/:action'
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I dont wanna use :as attribute, because many Controllers have this action (sort)

Comment: But i want pass :action, and rails find route in the current controller.. simple.. How can I do that? `<%= :action => 'sort' %>` not work